# Server validation doesn't work when i post via jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a class Question with properties like below:

```
[Required]
public string Subject { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

I try to do some server validation. I've included these scripts:

```
<script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_validate_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_validate_unobtrusive_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is the "create" view:

```
<dt><span>Question title*</span>please be specific but brief</dt>
<dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { @class = "boxsizingBorder" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Subject)</dd>
<dt><span>Question details</span></dt>
<dd>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content, 7, 30, new { @class = "boxsizingBorder" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Content)</dd>
```

When i try to post a new question like that:

```
$('#saveChanges').click(function () {
    $('#createQuestion').submit();
});
```

(`#saveChanges` is the id of my span and `#createQuestion` is the id of my form)

If I don't fill in the example Subject field I momentarily see an error message (field is required, etc.) but question is posted anyway. Is this happening because I'm trying to post the form using jQuery or what?

How should Server Validation work in this instance?

Comment: how's the form emitted ? via Html.BeginForm or via standard <FORM ../> tag ?

Comment: And if you perform a simple post (with an <input type='SUBMIT' /> it does works. I've faced something similar in the past, will dig in my code to see if I find something. (Was something related to call the validation in the submit() function of the form.

Comment: Maybe this will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618247/forcing-a-revalidate-on-mvc3-unobtrusive-remote-validation

Comment: Exactly-when i usu "standard" way it works.

Comment: just add a form submit function issuing the validate() call and return true or false accordingly. $('#form').submit(function() { ..... });

Comment: in here a quite complete example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054328/manual-form-validation-in-mvc-3-and-jquery

Comment: Yea,but example describes client validation,and i have problem with server validation,

Comment: Server validation? sorry I've been misleaded by js scripts (they're just for client validation). Can you inspect result of Model.IsValid in your action ?

Comment: I'm sorry-that comment should be sent for another person in another forum about another problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call Jquery validate before you submit to perform the validation. Something like:

```
$('#saveChanges').click(function (event) {
   $("#yourForm").validate();
   if ($("#yourForm").valid()) {
       $('#createQuestion').submit();
   }

   event.preventDefault; //this is needed if your saveChanges button is a submit button
});
```

Comment: preventDefault is preferred over return false;

Comment: This is an older question but I would suggest using .trigger('submit') instead of .submit. Using the trigger method should invoke the validation where calling .submit will simply submit the form.

Comment: @mattytommo While the docs say that .submit is short code for .trigger('submit') I've often found that using trigger will cause validation to fire. Maybe it was an isolated event just in my testing but here is a thread that discusses it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag

Comment: @NickBork Hmmm very strange! Something to be wary of I guess. Thanks :)