# MVC3 - Firing unobtrusive JavaScript on JQuery UI Autcomplete Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, unobtrusive-validation

combox I'm using unobtrusive validation in an MVC3 app.  I've got a dropdown list with a [Required] validator on it.  This is my Model (simplified):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select From Employee.")]
public string CurrentEmpId { get; set; }       

public List<SelectListItem> CurrentEmp { get; set; }
```

And this is my View (simplified):

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentAdvisers)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentEmpId, new SelectList(Model.CurrentEmp, "Value", "Text", Model.CurrentEmpId), "Please Select")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentEmpId)
```

Now this is all working bo diddly until I make the dropdown list into a JQuery UI combox  [jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) (see last argument).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentEmpId, new SelectList(Model.CurrentEmp, "Value", "Text", Model.CurrentEmpId), "Please Select", new { @class = "selAutoComplete" })
```

The validation fires OK when I press a submit button and nothing has been selected.  There is one annoying thing that doesn't work though.  When an error is fired, if I then go and correct the error by selecting something in the dropdown and tab out the error doesn't disappear.  This did happen when it was a normal select box.

It's probably to do with the fact that the `<select>` is now hidden and replaced by an `<input>` by JQuery, but I can't figure out how to fire the correct js to remove the error message.

Any help will be gratefully received!

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you using AutoComplete with `<select>`? Is it with the combobox example shown on jQuery UI's demo (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)?

Comment: Sorry William - yes that is exactly the one I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I've found the following solution works just fine:

[How to use jQuery to remotely validate a field that depends on another field in the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710548/how-do-i-use-jquery-validate-remote-validation-on-a-field-that-depends-on-another)

```
$("select.selAutoComplete").change(function() {
    $(this).removeData("previousValue"); //clear cache when changing group
    $("form").data('validator').element('select.selAutoComplete');
});
```

@William Niu - I tried your solution and off the top of my head, I couldn't see why this didn't work.  Thanks for taking the time to answer though.

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that validation of the select control did not get triggered when you tabbed out of the jQ-UI combobox. One thing you could try is to force a `blur` or `change` event on the select control right after you tab away from the combobox, e.g.:

```
$('#CurrentEmpId').next('input').blur(function(e) {
    $('#CurrentEmpId').change();
    //$('#CurrentEmpId').blur();    // try this line if the above does not work
});
```