# jquery.validate: addMethod with ajax not returning true

Tags: jquery, validation

This is my method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("password_verify_old", function(value, element){ 


     $.ajax({
         type: "GET", 
         url: verify_old_password_url,
         data: {oldPassword: value},   
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) { 
           return eval(msg);
         }
       });



}, "Old password is incorrect.");
```

Here, I'm calling my controller which returns just a "true" String. Why does the jquery.validate.js interpret this as 'false'?

Comment: maybe because ajax is asynchronous, so your validate function has already finished when the response arrives...

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you can add a validation method using addMethod that calls ajax

What you are looking for is remote option in the rules, which will make an ajax call to a url specified for the value in the input

```
   $(form).validate({
       rules:{ your_field :{
               required:true,
               remote: check_passwordurl,
```

Oh yea have your check password url return a boolean true or false, else you would need todo some extra coding as this SO shows
[How to use jQuery to remotely validate a field that depends on another field in the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710548/how-do-i-use-jquery-validate-remote-validation-on-a-field-that-depends-on-anothe)